# Get Locatioan using Fused Location Provider

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

i know that on stackoverflow are many questions about fused location manager. But no one solve my problem. So:
i made simple class using official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

and notice strange action. My onConnected method is never called. I have checked also onConnectionFailed and it's the same.
What is the problem?

My class:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double naviLat, naviLong;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @BindView(R.id.adView)
    AdView adView;
    @BindView(R.id.butnavi)
    ImageButton butnavi;
    private GPStracker gpStracker;
    private Location location;
    private RealmResults<RowModel> rowModels;
    private String shopName;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map2);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();



        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Log.d("ddsa", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " " +
            String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("aaa", "Failed");
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ddd.kkk'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName '4.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled false

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Is play services installed and up-to date on the device?

Comment: onConnectionFailed called?

Comment: do you have runtime Location Permission??

Comment: @Ryan - i test it on avd so i think that google-play-services should be up to date

Comment: @xabadal onConnectionFailed i think should be auto called when onConnection is false. But it doesn't work too.

Comment: @xbadal my persmissions from manifest looks like: permission
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> i don't use run time permissions because i'm testing on API 19

Comment: You don't need permissions to connect to the google api client @xbadal

Comment: @ArminOrlik make sure it's setup correctly using the follow guide - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: guys could it have something to do with multidex enable? my project has over 65k methods limit...

Comment: are you importing all Google play service in gradle? us this only com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6

Comment: yes also i think i need adress Api (for geocoder) mobile ads (for admob) maps(for show google maps)

Comment: unfortunately setting mutlidex = false doesn't solve my problem

Comment: maybe somebody want to check it by yourself and connect to my git?

Comment: paste your gradle file

Comment: is it possible that if my avd emulator hasn't google play store it could be problem??

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself because I lost it all day and maybe someone will use it. If you test your application on AVD please remember to clean the application cache every time - running several times the same application causes that not all changes made in the code update to AVD ...